# My infix wants to learn, my prefix is about

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is about
> My infix wants to learn
> My suffix wants to get things done
> My whole is a redecoration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are:

> REDO

My prefix is about

> RE

My infix wants to learn

> ED - as in Education

My suffix wants to get things done

> DO

My whole is a redecoration

> To Redo a room is to redecorate it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Refreshment

My prefix is about

> **Re** (meaning about or concerning)

My infix wants to learn

> **Freshmen** = first-year students at university.

My suffix wants to get things done

> **Ment** sounds like *meant* (in reference to an action done with purpose)

My whole is a redecoration

> Refreshment = the act of freshening up or redecorating

Comment: I think the whole and suffix seems a little dubious

Comment: Also freshmen like to party more than learn

Answer (score 2):

I think you are

> Amend

My prefix is about

> Am -- When you say "I am something", you are saying "About me is something".

My infix wants to learn

> Men -- Men, unlike other creatures, developed technology, and we are all progressing by learning everyday.

My suffix wants to get things done

> End

My whole is a redecoration

> Amend -- make minor changes in order to make it fairer, more accurate, or more up-to-date.