# Solving the Same Riddle Twice, Again

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

```
My prefix comes at my suffix
But the guys that are my infix
Demand that we add some fixes!
```

So we include:

```
My suffix fixes what was broken
My prefix and infix badly answer
The question we are trying to improve:
```

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer here is:

> **AMEND**

**First riddle:**

*My prefix comes at my suffix*

> Your prefix is **AMEN** which is the closing word that usually comes at (your suffix) the **END** of a prayer.

*But the guys that are my infix*
*Demand that we add some fixes!*

> Your infix is **MEN** ('guys'). And - of course - '*add some fixes*' (in the sense of *repairs*) is the literal meaning of AMEND!

**Second riddle:**

*My suffix fixes what was broken*

> To **MEND** means 'to *fix*'.

*My prefix and infix badly answer*
*The question we are trying to improve: What am I?*

> If your prefix is **AM** and your infix is **ME** then '(I) AM ME' is certainly a *bad answer* to the question 'What am I?' as it gives us no clarity or new information at all! In fact, that's perfectly ironic, since this second riddle is an attempted amendment to the first ('*trying to improve*'), yet it yields exactly the same answer, which is AMEND!

Comment: Here's my way to describe [the word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101817/70545) :)